# How to find a closed formula for this Fibonacci-like recursive definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

I have a recursive definition which is similar to the Fibonacci-numbers:

$n_1 = 1$ (I)

$n_2 = 2$ (II)

$n_k = n_{k-2} + n_{k-1} + 1$ (III)

I am looking for a closed formula for it.

If that $+1$ weren't on the end of (III), everything would be very easily linearizable, because I could apply matrices and solve the problem in its own system of eigenvectors. This is how the closed formula of the Fibonacci-numbers is derived.

But now, with this $+1$, this solution doesn't work any more.

What to do?

Comment: Have you computed the first few values of the sequence?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes. 1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20. Nothing very obvious.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Wait, its difference sequence is the Fibonacci-numbers!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown TYVM!

Comment: solve the characteristic equation $x^2=x+1$, find roots, homegeneous solutions $n_k=ar_1^k+br_2^k$ and a particular solution for $RHS=1$.

Comment: I posted an answer that calculates the general solution in a general way. I also noted why the first differences are the Fibonacci numbers as you noticed.

Comment: @zwim Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use recurrence annihilators, or equivalently, the shift operator, as follows:

$$F(n)=F(n-2)+F(n-1)+1$$
$$F(n+2)−F(n+1)−F(n)=1$$

Let $\partial$ denote $\frac{d}{dn}$. Than
$$e^{h\partial}F(n)=F(n+h)$$
which can be used to express the above as

$$(e^{2\partial}-e^\partial -1)F(n)=1$$
which can be factored
$$(e^\partial-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(e^\partial-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})F(n)=1$$
what is left to do, is to notice that $(e^\partial-1)$ annihilates a constant. This is why the first differences of the sequence you computed are the Fibonacci numbers($(e^\partial-1)$ is the first difference). As such
$$(e^\partial-1)(e^\partial-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})(e^\partial-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})F(n)=0$$
which leads to a general solution

$$F(n)=c_0(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+c_1(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+c_2$$

The constants $c_i$ can be computed from initial conditions.

If you want to learn more about such computations, and proofs of the used theorems, you can read this post on [Recurrence annihilators and Algebraic encodings](https://zigasajovic.github.io/Recurrence-annihilators-and-Algebraic-encodings/). The post also contains a recurrence solver, that will show you these calculations, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_k = n_k + 1$, we have
$$n_k = n_{k-1} + n_{k-2} + 1 \quad\implies\quad f_k = f_{k-1} + f_{k-2}$$
Compare this to the recurrence relation of Fibonacci numbers
$$F_k = F_{k-1} + F_{k-2}$$
and notice $f_1 = 2 = F_3, f_2 = 3 = F_4$, we find
$$f_k = F_{k+2} \quad\implies\quad n_k = F_{k+2} - 1$$

In general, if you have a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients

$$x_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^m a_k x_{n-k} = 0$$

whose characteristic polynomial $\chi(\lambda) = \lambda^m + \sum_{k=1}^m a_k \lambda^{m-k}$ doesn't vanish at $1$, the  inhomogeneous recurrence relation
with a polynomial $P(x)$ as source term:
$$x_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^m a_k x_{n-k} = P(n)$$
will have a particular solution of polynomial in $n$ with same degree as $P(x)$.

In your case, $P(x) = 1$, so your recurrence relation will have a constant sequence as particular solution. You just need to figure out that constant and reduce your problem to that of Fibonacci sequences.

Answer (score 0):

For @LordSharkTheUnknown 's pretty comment, I computed the first few values of the sequence: $1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20...$

Its difference sequence are the Fibonacci-numbers. The hypothesis can be easily proven by induction.

Since we have closed formula for the Fibonacci-numbers, which is

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n- \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n $$

it is already easy to convert to a series with elemental identities.